# Json string not getting appended properly in IE 8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

My controller returns this string like so:

```
return Json(indication.Model.PrepaymentExport);
```

I append it to the div on the front end like so:

```
$('#termSheetPrinted').append(data + '<br>');
```

It works in FF but not in IE =/

I seem to get this in IE but I don't know if it relates?

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 1 Apr 2011 20:47:41 UTC

Message: Unterminated string constant
Line: 133844620
Char: 88
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/analysis/b16fc100-05ad-4631-882e-908e707480fd

Edit:

the returned string looks like this:

```
<div style="font-weight:bold">Prepayment Value</div><table id="TotalValueStringtableId" class="exposureGrid" width="150px" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td></td><td colspan="5" class="resultsSubHeader" align="center"> Time Remaining </td></tr><tr><td class="resultsSubHeader">Replacement Rate</td><td class="resultsSubHeader">4 yrs</td><td class="resultsSubHeader">3 yrs</td><td class="resultsSubHeader">2 yrs</td><td class="resultsSubHeader">1 yrs</td></tr><tr><td targetrate="">3.38</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">$390,712</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">$298,676</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">$196,304</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">$99,828</td></tr><tr><td targetrate="">2.88</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">$197,881</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">$150,455</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">$98,663</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">$50,049</td></tr><tr><td targetrate="">1.88</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">($201,638)</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">($152,729)</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">($99,699)</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">($50,323)</td></tr><tr><td targetrate="">1.38</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">($406,621)</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">($307,772)</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">($200,445)</td><td undefined="" style="white-space: nowrap;">($100,920)</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Also, it seems to work SOMETIMES, but not all the time =/

Comment: When do you get that error?  When the JSON is returned, or on page load?

Comment: I get it when the I try to do anything with the Json that gets returned. What gets returned from the server is a c# string that represents html code

Comment: posted the returned string above.

Comment: Are you returning a JSON string (ie: { "content" : "myContent" } ) or just that string?

Comment: Considering that it works sometimes it is most probably related to the data that is being returned. The string you posted, is this being returned when the operation succeeds or fails?

Comment: The next time you get this error; could you post the json that came back in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem the other day.  [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) results are set to cache by default.  Most browsers ignore it, but IE doesn't.  Just set the ajax call in js to cache false, and it should start working.

Answer (score 1):

There is something bizarre about your server code. You have shown HTML in the response and yet you return Json on the server. This makes no sense. If you have some string on the server which is HTML then return raw HTML like this:

```
return Content(indication.Model.PrepaymentExport, "text/html");
```

and to fetch it from the client:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/foo',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#termSheetPrinted').append(data + '<br/>');
    }
});
```

If `PrepaymentExport` is some object that you want to serialize to JSON then return Json from the server as you did but in the success callback you cannot append objects to the DOM, only HTML. So in this case:

```
$.getJSON('/home/foo', function(data) {
    // data here will be an object so don't append it directly to the DOM.
    // use some string property which represents HTML or build tags manually
    // without more details about what indication.Model.PrepaymentExport represents
    // on the server I cannot help much
});
```